# Properly escape / in sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I'm attemping to make a script which will take the 1st positional argument in `$foo` and remove all the lines before the `$foo` line in `files.txt`. However I keep getting the following error:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unknown command: f`. My input is `recup_dir.6/f5681240.mpg`, I have even tried escaping the `/` by  `recup_dir.6\/f5681240.mpg` but it didn't help. I also searched around for different methods of escaping text but non helped. My code is:

```
foo=$1;
sed -i "0,/^file $foo$/d" files.txt
```

EDIT: Making the question more clear, say I have a file named `files.txt`

```
file ab/c
file eg/f
file hi/j
file xy/z
```

Now I want to remove all elements before a specific element say `hij`, so I use the command `sed -i '0,/^file hi\/j$/d' files.txt` which works fine.

However when I try to use this as part of a script shown above it fails.
Running `./script.sh eg\/f` it fails with error `` sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unknown command: `f' ``

Thanks

Comment: Try: `sed -i "0,#^file $foo$#d" files.txt`. it's not necessary to use always `/` as the separator in sed.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon it gives me an error `sed: -e expression #1, char 3: unexpected ','`

Comment: It seems the problem is with the `,` after 0 character. I'm no sure if that's the correct syntax for sed.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365103/5378459 this is the answer I was using to make the sed command

Comment: It's weird , I'm not rally sure what is happening. I will have to read more about sed :).

Comment: Zero is not a valid address.  There is no line zero. Using `0` as the start of a range is not portable, although it might work in some implementations. It would be better to describe what you want to do.

Comment: @Kusalananda `sed '0,/^file recup_dir.4\/f4787984.mpg$/d' files.txt > files2.txt` this works fine when executed directly in the terminal, but fails when running in a script using the above code.

Comment: Oh, I see now. Ok. Easy. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your string contains a slash character.  When injected by the shell into the `sed` expression, that character creates a syntax error (it ends the regular expression early).

One way to fix this is to ensure that every `/` is escaped as `\/` in the string you inject, but this is a bit awkward.  Another way is to use a delimiter that is not found in the string:

```bash
foo=$1
sed -i "1,\:^file $foo$:d" files.txt
```

Note that the first occurrence of the delimiter needs to be escaped in the expression and that `0` is not generally a valid start of a range.

If you also want to output the matching line:

```bash
foo=$1
sed -i "1,\:^file $foo$: { \:^file $foo$: p; d; }" files.txt
```

---

Alternative solution:

```bash
awk -v file="$foo" 'output; $0 == "file " file { output = 1 }' files.txt
```

This outputs each line if the variable `output` is not zero or blank.  The variable is set to `1` whenever a line is `file`  followed by the string given on the command line to the variable `file`.

If you also want to output the matching line:

```bash
awk -v file="$foo" '$0 == "file " file { output = 1 }; output' files.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! Can you explain why this delimiter worked whereas `sed -i "0,#^file $foo$#d" files.txt` posted by Edgar above didn't?

Comment: @DentFuse The `#` was not `\#`.